# Howto fix x509: cannot validate certificate for <ip> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: go, tls1.2, x509

I'm using go http client to connect to iot device which has self-signed cert. I already have

```
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            certPool,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{tlsClientCert},
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    },
```

Nevertheless although `InsecureSkipVerify=true` go still tries to verify the certificate:

```
x509: cannot validate certificate for <ip> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

As I can't change the cert on the device- what part of the TLS client config can I modify to accept it?

**UPDATE**

The go error can be reproduced running https://github.com/jbardin/gotlsscan/blob/master/main.go against the device:

```
Testing TLS1.2
    ...
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA            [NOT SUPPORTED]
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256       [NOT SUPPORTED] x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.1.145 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256         [NOT SUPPORTED]
    ...
```

This is what openssl says when running `openssl s_client -connect <ip:port>`:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = DE, O = Bebro, OU = ULK High GEN 1, CN = ICCPD...
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, O = Bebro, OU = ULK High GEN 1, CN = ICCPD...
verify return:1
4460842604:error:1401E410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:1200:SSL alert number 40
4460842604:error:1401E0E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:ssl handshake failure:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:585:
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=DE/O=Bebro/OU=ULK High GEN 1/CN=ICCPD...
  i:/C=DE/O=Bebro/OU=ULK High GEN 1/CN=ICCPD...
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=DE/O=Bebro/OU=ULK High GEN 1/CN=ICCPD...
issuer=/C=DE/O=Bebro/OU=ULK High GEN 1/CN=ICCPD...
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 969 bytes and written 178 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
    Session-ID: 9C7D...
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: AC9E...
    Start Time: 1600892515
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
```

**UPDATE** I'm running latest go 1.15.2

Comment: You could specify a `Host` in your request that is in the cert's SANs.

Comment: All I have is the device's name from DNS-SD. As part of the application I don't even get as far as reading its cert/SAN so not sure how I would do that. Also: the error message contains the remote IP so its the local go client complaining. It shouldn't even try to validate the certificate here?

Comment: @andig: Setting `InsecureSkipVerify` ought to be enough, and I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. Can you post a minimal but complete working program that demonstrates the problem, along with the complete error message?

Comment: I've updated example and openssl diagnosis.

Comment: Can you please provide the go code snippet where you are making the request?

Comment: It‘s exactly the application mentioned above, see https://github.com/jbardin/gotlsscan/blob/master/main.go#L89. My code is more convoluted but leads to the same error as linked repo.

Comment: @andig: Thanks for providing that. Which version of Go are you using? A few suggestions to try: (1) output the value of `insecure`, just to make absolutely sure it's really being set to `true` - stranger things have happened; (2) you should generally either set `ServerName` or `InsecureSkipVerify`, but not both, so try *not* setting `ServerName` if `insecure` is `true`; (3) you shouldn't modify a `tls.Config` after it's been passed to a `tls` package function, so try moving its definition inside your inner loop to create a new config each time.

Comment: @Crowman I'm facing similar issue, I've pykmip server running in one VM(10.20.30.40) and i'm trying to make connection to that server using client certificate, here , my requirement is not to use InsecureSkipVerify to true, but false. After some search some places it mentioned to add SAN in certificate , hence added the same, so certificate will contain one filed called SAN and it will have some value, I configured "ServerName" with the same name but couldn't succeed. Is there any other way to implement this ?

Comment: @imaheshwarans: That sounds like a question, not a comment, so I suggest you ask a question, including all the relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

This might work,

In certificate there is a field called "SANs", we need to add 'hostname' in this SAN list.

[image: Properties]

once this is added the same name should be added in TLS configuration using "ServerName" filed. after this configuration this will be resolved. In SANS property I've added "test.com" so I configured TLS as follows,

```
        ServerName:   "test.com",
        RootCAs:      pool,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{clientCert},
        MinVersion:   tls.VersionTLS12,
```

Since the certificate you;re using may not contain any SANs, this error is occurred. I'm still exploring on it, If you guys any comments on this ,kindly leave a reply.